# Passing Stored Procedure query result from JSonResult to Ajax

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, jsonresult

Good Day! I'm trying to display the result of a stored procedure query into a textbox on my page. This stored procedure only returns one result which is the daily sales. I'm trying to do this passing through JSonresult so that I can pass it to an ajax in my view page. But I couldn't seem to succeed in passing it.

I have a table named **ORDER** that has a **ORDER_DATE** & **NET_AMOUNT** column. I need to display the sum of the net_amount for the current day. Here is my query:

```html
SELECT SUM(NET_AMOUNT) AS DAILY_SALES
FROM [ORDER]
WHERE ORDER_DATE = GETDATE()
```

I then call this stored procedure in my controller with this Method:

```html
        public JsonResult GetSalesToday()
        {
            DataTable dtTable = new DataTable();
            List<string> lstSales = new List<string>();


            string strQuery = "SP_DAILY_SALES";

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString());
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dtTable);


            foreach (DataRow row in dtTable.Rows)
            {
                lstSales.Add(row["DAILY_SALES"].ToString());
            }


            var DailySales = new
            {
                SALESTODAY = lstSales
            };


            return Json(DailySales, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

and then calling it to the my view with this:

```html
  $.ajax(
                       {
                           datatype: "json",
                           type: "POST",
                           url: "/Sales/GetSalesToday",
                           data: JSON,
                           success: function (data) {
                               DailySales(data);
                           },
                           error: function () { alert("Error"); }
                       });
```

How do I call it then to my textbox?

```html
 <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor("DailySales", "Sales", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4" })
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-xs-6">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor("DailySales", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor("DailySales", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Where am I going wrong? Can someone help me out on this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your SP_DAILY_SALES sp returns ? What is the value in DailySales ?

Comment: what does the function `DailySales(data);` do?

Comment: @Shyju it returns the SUM(NET_AMOUNT) as DAILY_SALES which I then  pass to lstSales. I created the var DailySales and assigned lstSales to another variable which is SALESTODAY . DailySales is what I pass on to the ajax in my view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the sum, just keep a variable for that and return just that.

```
decimal total = 0.0M;

foreach (DataRow row in dtTable.Rows)
{
   total  += Convert.ToInt32(row["DAILY_SALES"]);
}

return Json(total,JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
```

and in your ajax call's success call back, read the value and assign to the textbox by using jQuery `val()` method.

```
 success: function (data){
                           $("#DailySales").val(data);
                         },
```

If your stored procedure is return a single scalar value, you do not need to loop through the data row ! You may consider using the `ExecuteScalar` method as well. Also I changed your method to use `using` so that the connections will be closed properly.

Assuming your stored procedure is returning a single decimal value.

```
public JsonResult GetSalesToday()
{
    var strQuery = "SP_DAILY_SALES";
    decimal total = 0.0M;

    var conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString();

    using (var con = new SqlConnection(conStr)))
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, con))
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            total = (decimal)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }

    return Json(total, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Also, I see you have some wrong code in your view. `TextBoxFor` and `LabelFor` helper methods does not take a string as argument. You need to use `Html.TextBox` and `Html.Label` method

```
@Html.Label("DailySales", "Sales",new { @class = "col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4" })
@Html.TextBox("DailySales", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Hi @Shyju it returns an error in this line **total + = Convert.ToInt32(row["DAILY_SALES"]);** 1st error: **; expected** which points to **Convert** and the 2nd error: **Invalid expression term '='** pointing to this **=**

Comment: @KylieIrwin Sorry ! Extra space ! Fixed now. This code should work fine.

Comment: The errors are gone now. Just an error with how I call it in this **@Html.LabelFor("DailySales", "Sales")**

Comment: @KylieIrwin I made another update to the answer to improve your server method.

Comment: Hi @Shyju ! I know this has already been marked as answer but I've had a trouble with this **total = (decimal)cmd.ExecuteScalar();** The error is **Specified cast is not valid.**

Comment: Hi @Shyju ! I know this has already been marked as answer but I've had a trouble with this total = (decimal)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); The error is Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120805/discussion-between-kylie-irwin-and-shyju).

Comment: As i mentioned in my answer earlier, the code assumes your SP returns a single **decimal** value. If it is returning an int, use an int variable in your code instead of decimal.

Comment: what if the query returns a null value though? Like what if there is no record to return for that date?

Comment: then use a `decimal?` (Nullable decimal). And wherever you display the value of it, do a null check.

Comment: got it now. I altered my stored procedure so that it would return 0.00 if the result of the query is null. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
`decimal total = 0.0;
foreach (DataRow row in dtTable.Rows)
{
   lstSales.Add(row["DAILY_SALES"].ToString());
   total = total + Convert.ToInt32(row["DAILY_SALES"]);
}
return Json(total,JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);`
```

Comment: @Kylie Irwin can you try this

Comment: I did. It returns this error: **Error 4 'int' does not contain a definition for 'M' and no extension method 'M' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Comment: This works just fine now. Just an error with how I call it in this **@Html.LabelFor("DailySales", "Sales")**